# Prove by induction that sum of binomial series = 2^n.

Tags: induction, binomial-coefficients

[image: This is the description of the problem]

I did prove the base case where n=0. Now I was trying to prove the induction step(n+1).

I tried doing:
$$2^{1+n} = 2^{n} + \sum \binom{n+1}{k}$$
$$2^{1+n} = 2^{n} + \sum \binom{n}{k} + \sum \binom{n}{k-1}$$
$$2^{1+n} = 2^{n} + 2^{n} + \frac{n!}{\left ( k-1 \right )!\left ( n-k-1 \right )!}$$

I tried cancelling the last part of the equation, but it doesn't work. Could someone explain and show me the way.

Comment: So, it means that the way I was doing it was wrong?

Comment: It only means that that question has been posted and answered before.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos If I don't understand a certain part of the post you suggested, should I post another question? Not sure what to do as the question has already been answered.

Comment: Yes, but clear about the fact that your question is about a step in a proof of the equality not the equality itself.